# Set current context SPWeb focus on SPTreeView

Tags: 2010, navigation

I'm using an customized SPTreeView (UserControl) embed on the masterpage, any ideas how to set the selectedNode that correspond to the contextWeb or using another approach?

spregards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using TreeView instead of SPTreeView:

```
protected void LeftNavTreeView_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                        LeftNavTreeView.CollapseAll();

                        var treeNodeToExpand = LeftNavTreeView.SelectedNode;

                        while (treeNodeToExpand != null)
                        {
                                treeNodeToExpand.Expand();
                                treeNodeToExpand = treeNodeToExpand.Parent;
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's little tricky.. Let's assume you have following binding for your SPTreeview

```
<DataBindings>
                <asp:TreeNodeBinding SelectAction="Select" NavigateUrlField="" TextField="EncodedName"
                    Target="_blank" ValueField="Name" />
            </DataBindings>
```

Then, in PreRender, you need to set the SelectedNodePath as shown below

```
 protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {

                WebTreeView.SelectedNodePath = "value that corresponds to current web";

        }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @ashish-patel, but still not working.

`protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
var web = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
WebTreeView.SelectedNodePath = web.Url;
WebTreeView.AutoExpandSelectedNode = true;
}`